# REST API Error handling - Should a resource method throw a business exception?

Tags: rest, error-handling, exception, jersey, jax-rs

I'm designing & implementing how our REST api would handle errors. I did some reading on the topic.

I read at many places (for example here: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/error-handling-in-rest-api-with-jersey/) that you can write an ExceptionMapper that will handle the business exceptions & map it to the response output. I somehow don't find this is right as I feel business errors should not be thrown out to the Jersey layer since it doesn't know anything about it and all the business errors should be handled by the API code itself - may be by writing some utility method that will insert all the errors into the response structure.

I think it's okay to throw the exceptions that you can't do anything about (like unchecked exceptions) to the Jersey/framework layer. But is using an ExceptionMapper and throwing a business error from a resource method to Jersey - a right way to handle business errors?

Comment: What other options are there? Do they make more sense? That's all you need to ask yourself